# how does Chronicle-wire support schema evolution?

Tags: chronicle

I am new to [Chronicle-wire](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire). In the document it claims support for "setting of fields to the default, if not available" in the schema evolution section.

Do we have an example of how this works?

I have an example of adding an array field to a simple Marshallable object. When reading the journals contains the old version of the object, how can we set a default value (eg. new String[0]) to the field instead of a null?

Answer (score 0):

There're a few ways to achieve that, one example is below:

```
public class TestMarshallable implements Marshallable {
    private long a;
    private int b;
    private String newField = "defaultValue";
    @Override
    public void readMarshallable(@NotNull WireIn wire) throws IORuntimeException {
        a = wire.read("a").int64();
        b = wire.read("b").int32();
        if (wire.bytes().readRemaining() > 0)
            newField = wire.read("newField").text();
    }
}
```

In this example, it is assumed that your new field will be written last, hence you can simply check if there's more to read - and do so. Default value is the one you assign to the field.
More complicated, but way more flexible way:

```
public class TestMarshallable implements Marshallable {
    private long a = 0;
    private int b = 1;
    private String newField = "defaultValue";

    @Override
    public void readMarshallable(@NotNull WireIn wire) throws IORuntimeException {
        @NotNull StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
        while (!wire.isEmpty()) {
            @NotNull ValueIn in = wire.read(name);
            if (StringUtils.isEqual(name, "a"))
                a = in.int64();
            else if (StringUtils.isEqual(name, "b"))
                b = in.int32();
            else if (StringUtils.isEqual(name, "newField"))
                newField = in.text();
            else
                unexpectedField(name, in);
            wire.consumePadding();
        }
    }
}
```

In the last example readMarshallable simply overwrites the fields it could find in the stream leaving others with default values (NB this can also be used to save certain amount of writes, if you often write default values you can skip them altogether in writeMarshallable)